# Xulrunner force links to open in a single window

Tags: c#, xulrunner

Ive got a C# programm, that works using xulrunner embeded into the form. But when I click on a link with  target="_blank" property, it opens a new window for me. What I need is to force all such links open in existing browser window. Can you please help me with this as soon as I was not able to find any info regarding this topic on the net. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add `geckoWebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += LoadingFinished;` to your form load

Than use this;

```
   private void LoadingFinished(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (geckoWebBrowser1.Document != null && geckoWebBrowser1.Document.Body != null)
        {
            foreach (var anchor in geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
            {
                var targetAttributeValue = anchor.GetAttribute("target");
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(targetAttributeValue))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(anchor.GetAttribute("href") as string + " changed href from " + targetAttributeValue as string + " to _self");
                    anchor.SetAttribute("target", "_self");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This replaces the _blank with _self. It helps.